# Java HashMap key to jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can i access the `HashMap` key to the `JQuery`? I want to have the key it self to use in `typeahead` of [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/index.html).

I'm using Gson to parse the HashMap to Gson:

```
HashMap<String, String> source = new HashMap<String, String>();
put("key","value");

response.setContentType( "application/json" );
response.setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8" );
response.getWriter().write( new Gson().toJson( source ) );
```

Code of my typeahead:

```
$('#textbox').typeahead({
    source: function(query, process){
        return $.get('URL', {query: query},
                      function(data){
              return process(data.key);
              },'json');
        },
    items: 10
});
```

at `return process(data);` i want to have the key of the HashMap it self

Comment: You probably want `process(data)` since the map **is** the root JSON element. Note, though, that [you can't return anything from an ajax call since it's asynchronous.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/139010)

Comment: So i can only return 1 array of value? i tried data.key because i want it to return the key not the value. Isn't that possible?

Comment: No - you can't **return** anything from an ajax call. I don't understand what you mean by "the key". Try looking at the output of [`Object.keys(data)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: I see, i'll search for a work around

Answer (score 0):

Why its highly possible.

```
just use JSON.stringfy(data.key);
```